# AsyncTasks and tabs

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am trying to work with AsyncTasks in Android 2.1 but get errors on my code. 
I want to display to the user logo and  after that to display my tabs but get errors on my AsyncTask.If you can see my code and tell me where my errors are.

the error is

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity    ComponentInfo{com.example.News/startPakage.tabs}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a TabHost whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.tabhost'
```

where my code is:

```
   public class tabs extends TabActivity {

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.logoscreen);
    new GetDataTask(this).execute();
    private class GetDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer> {
    Context     context;

    GetDataTask(Context context){this.context=context;}
    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {

          int waited = 0;
          while (waited < 5000) {
          try {
            this.wait(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
             waited += 100;
          }
            return 1;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
        tabs.this.setContentView(R.layout.tabs);
      //setContentView(R.layout.tabs);

        TabHost tabHost= (TabHost)tabs.this.findViewById( android.R.id.tabhost );


        //


        TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
        Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab

        // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
        intent = new Intent().setClass(context,start.class);

        // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Heb news").setIndicator("Heb news").setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        // Do the same for the other tabs
        intent = new Intent().setClass(context, rusNewsP.ListRusNews.class);

        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Rus News").setIndicator("Rus News").setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);
        tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
    }
}
```

And  my xml is:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="5dp">
    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

thanks a lot!

Comment: Hopefully when you pasted your code in, you left out two closing curly braces at the very end.  If not, that's your problem.  Also, when pasting in code, make sure all your tabbing is in good order, it's difficult to read code when you can't tell what method half the code belongs to.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're using a `TabActivity` but the first time you set the content view you do NOT have a tabhost (in the `R.layout.logoscreen` file). You can add the tabhost to your logo layout (it won't hurt) and it should work. Alternatively, you can split the code into two activities and just kick off a new activity after the AsyncTask is done.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:
 Give id as : `android:id="@+id/tabhost"`

and in your code use:

```
TabHost tabHost= (TabHost)tabs.this.findViewById( R.id.tabhost );
```

Do this for all the declarations in your xml file.

Comment: did what you said but gets : Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a TabHost whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.tabhost'